# PiCamera - Get FPS

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am attempting to record video to a file in Python-OpenCV and I am finding settings the frame rate manually to be too inaccurate, I found a solution online for C++ posted below.

```
cam.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

This should get the camera's current FPS as long as the camera supports ioctl for pulling this information.

My setup is using a Raspberry Pi2 with the Pi NoIr camera module, running Python with the PiCamera library for accessing the CSI camera, my question is twofold:

Does the Pi camera support ioctl for getting fps?

If so, how can I achieve this with Python or picamera library?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the default framerate in python then it will be set to 30fps.
See documentation, [picamera.camera Module][1]for the default frame rate.

For change the framerate you can do:

```
camera.framerate=25
```

Camera must not be recording for this change to take effect.

But for get the real fps if you do some extra process you should do a manual calculation like

```
 while True:
  ...
  start_time = time.monotonic()
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  elapsed_sec = (time.monotonic() - start_time)
  fps = 1/elapsed_sec
```